# celery trying shutdown worker by raising SystemExit in task_postrun signal but always hangs and the main process never exits

Tags: python, signals, celery, systemexit

I'm trying to shutdown the main celery process by raisin SystemExit() in the task_postrun signal. The signal gets fired just fine, and the exception gets raised, but the worker never completely exits and just hangs there.

HOW DO I MAKE THIS WORK?

Am I forgetting some setting somewhere?

Below is the code that I'm using for the worker (worker.py):

```
from celery import Celery
from celery import signals

app = Celery('tasks',
    set_as_current = True,
    broker='amqp://guest@localhost//',
    backend="mongodb://localhost//",
)

app.config_from_object({
    "CELERYD_MAX_TASKS_PER_CHILD": 1,
    "CELERYD_POOL": "solo",
    "CELERY_SEND_EVENTS": True,
    "CELERYD_CONCURRENCY": 1,
    "CELERYD_PREFETCH_MULTIPLIER": 1,
})

def shutdown_worker(**kwargs):
    print("SHUTTING DOWN WORKER (RAISING SystemExit)")
    raise SystemExit()

import tasks

signals.task_postrun.connect(shutdown_worker)

print("STARTING WORKER")
app.worker_main()
print("WORKER EXITED!")
```

and below is the code for tasks.py:

```
from celery import Celery,task
from celery.signals import task_postrun
import time

from celery.task import Task

class Blah(Task):
    track_started = True
    acks_late = False

    def run(config, kwargs):
        time.sleep(5)
        return "SUCCESS FROM BLAH"

def get_app():
    celery = Celery('tasks',
        broker='amqp://guest@localhost//',
        backend="mongodb://localhost//"
    )
    return celery
```

To test this, first thing I do is run the worker code (`python worker.py`), then I queue up a task like so:

```
>>> import tasks
>>> results = []
>>> results.append(tasks.Blah.delay({}))
```

The output I see from the worker is this:

```
STARTING WORKER

 -------------- celery@hostname v3.0.9 (Chiastic Slide)
---- **** ----- 
--- * ***  * -- [Configuration]
-- * - **** --- . broker:      amqp://guest@localhost:5672//
- ** ---------- . app:         tasks:0x26f3050
- ** ---------- . concurrency: 1 (solo)
- ** ---------- . events:      ON
- ** ---------- 
- *** --- * --- [Queues]
-- ******* ---- . celery:      exchange:celery(direct) binding:celery
--- ***** ----- 

[2012-11-06 15:59:16,761: WARNING/MainProcess] celery@hostname has started.
[2012-11-06 15:59:21,785: WARNING/MainProcess] SHUTTING DOWN WORKER (RAISING SystemExit)
```

I was expecting the python code to return from the call to `app.worker_main()` and then to print `WORKER EXITED` and then for the process to exit completely. This never happens, and the worker process has to be `kill -KILL {PID}`ed for it to go away (it's not able to consume any other tasks either.

I guess my main question would be:

HOW DO I MAKE THE CODE RETURN FROM `app.worker_main()`?

I'd like to be able to completely restart the worker process (by having the process ***COMPLETELY*** exit) after `X` number of tasks have been executed.

***UPDATE*** I figured out what the worker is hanging on - the worker (`WorkController`) is hanging on a call to `self.stop` after it catches the `SystemExit` exception.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hate it when I end up answering my own question.

Anywhoo, it was blocking on a join call on the `Mediator` component inside the `WorkController` (calls `stop()` on the `Mediator` component, inside stop, it `join`s).

I got rid of the `Mediator` component by disabling all rate limits (should be this by default, but it's not for some reason).

You can disable all rate limits with the setting:

```
CELERY_DISABLE_ALL_RATE_LIMITS: True
```

Hope this helps somebody else down the road too.

Peace

Comment: Option renamed to CELERY_DISABLE_RATE_LIMITS in current version of Celery. Its default value is defined by CELERY_DEFAULT_RATE_LIMIT which is no limit if you don't change.